# What does this SQL join do?

Tags: sql

The join below is what I think is called a theta join, non-equi join. Am I right in saying that an equi join is for what matches, and that non-equi joins are for what doesnt match. Then how does the following non-equi join work?

```
SELECT E.ENAME, E.SAL, S.GRADE 
FROM EMPTBL E, SALGRADE S
WHERE E.SAL
BETWEEN S.LOSAL AND S.HISAL;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed! (BTW, that's an INNER JOIN, written in an old-fashioned way.)

Comment: query would cross join all records from emp with salgrade and  fetch employee where salary is greater or equal to LOSAL and greater or equal to HISAL from salgrade

Answer (score 1):

avoid coma separated join use modern explicit join

```
SELECT E.ENAME, E.SAL, S.GRADE 
FROM EMPTBL E join  SALGRADE S
on E.SAL>=S.LOSAL and E.SAL<=S.HISAL
```

Comment: I don't understand what either join do. Plus the coma separated join is allowed in Oracle. This part confuses most, what does                                          
    WHERE E.SAL
    BETWEEN S.LOSAL AND S.HISAL                                                              , or your example of esal>s.losal do

Answer (score 1):

### Comma-separated joins versus ANSI joins:

Comma-separated joins are a thing of the past (they have been made redundant as per SQL standard in the year 1992) and should not be used anymore. If the tables are not related, we'd replace the comma with the word `CROSS JOIN` to make the intention clear, i.e.

```
SELECT e.ename, e.sal, s.grade 
FROM emptbl e, salgrade s
```

is

```
SELECT e.ename, e.sal, s.grade 
FROM emptbl e
CROSS JOIN salgrade s
```

In your case, however, you have a join condition.

```
SELECT e.ename, e.sal, s.grade 
FROM emptbl e, salgrade s
WHERE e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal;
```

is

```
SELECT e.ename, e.sal, s.grade 
FROM emptbl e
INNER JOIN salgrade s OB e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal;
```

What this join does is: combine every `emptbl` record with all `salgrade` records where the salary falls in the `salgrade` range. This is supposedly just one row only, because the salary grades probably won't overlap.

```
e.sal BETWEEN s.losal AND s.hisal
```

can also be written as

```
e.sal <= s.losal AND e.sal >= s.hisal
```

### Example:

**emptbl**

```
ename | sal
------+-----
John  | 1000
Jane  | 1500
```

**salgrade**

```
grade | losal | hisal
------+-------+------
low   |     0 |   800
med   |   801 |  1200
high  |  1201 |  2000
```

**result**

```
ename | sal  | grade
------+------+------
John  | 1000 | med      <-- because 1000 BETWEEN  801 AND 1200
Jane  | 1500 | high     <-- because 1500 BETWEEN 1201 AND 2000
```

### Equi joins versus Non-Equi joins:

A non-equi join does the same thing as an equi join, by the way, so it is not necessary to know this vocabulary. The only difference is that an equi join joins on `=` and the non-equi join joins on other comparisions, e.g. `<=`.

Comment: This is helpful. The join example I posted above posted is what I'm being taught currently in college without no explanation. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: You see from our reactions that this join syntax should not be taught anymore. It can be mentioned (like: "this is how we joined in the 1980s"), but not taught as if it were still up-to-date. You should tell your teacher. It seems weird to teach something from a thirty-year-old book.